# Why linq extension methods return concrete type

Tags: c#, linq

I know the benefit of declaring interface type instead of concrete type in method signatures. We can find a lot of explanation around here and I won't list them, that's not the point of my question.

My question is about linq. Why, when we saw that declaring interface types in methods signatures for API is a better practice, some linq extension methods are returning concrete type?

For example:

- [`ToList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx) return a `List<>` and not an `IList<>`.
- [`ToDictionary()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `Dictionary<>` and not an `IDictionary<>`
- etc

I was wondering it because I planed to extends the Enumerable extensions methods with my owns and my good practices were telling me to declare interface types when I remembered linq was declaring concrete implementations.

So what should I do? Declare concrete type or interface type?

Comment: I dare say, it's actually good practice to accept the most generic types in order to provide some functionality and return the most specialized types (that don't interfere with possible implementation changes) that can be returned.

Comment: Imagine `ToList()` would return `IList`. Would you really check `IList.IsReadOnly` for each returned IList before trying to modify the returned list? Hint: you should do if it returned `IList` without a more specific contract.

Answer (score -2):

IList and IDictionary are interfaces (blueprints) for what those types should contain in their definitions, not implementations that you can use for instances of the class.

Because you are specifically asking for a List (with ToList) or Dictionary (with ToDictionary), you are getting an actual instance of List/Dictionary.